# Is it possible to use boost to serialize and pretty-print polymorphic classes?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization, boost-fusion

Is there a minimal way to use boost for marshalling/unmarshalling as well as pretty-printing structs with their field-names (RTTI?) ?  It seems like you could use [`boost::fusion`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html) and then somehow automatically implement the [`boost::serialization`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) interface using the `boost::fusion` functions, but I'm not sure how to approach this, or if it is possible.

Comment: Too broad to answer. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+reflection&submit=search

Comment: Really.  Marshalling/Unmarshalling combined with pretty-printing using the boost library seems broad to you?  I know that _reflection_ is a large topic, but this nexus of topics seems rather specific.